# Share Internet via Ethernet from Mac OSX to Ubuntu (10.04)?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, networking, internet

Anyone know how to share an Internet connection over Ethernet, from Mac OSX to Ubuntu (Lucid Lynx 10.04)?

EDIT

Mac receives Internet access via Airport (Wireless).

I don't need any Mac-Ubuntu file sharing, just need to access the Internet through the Mac.

(The reason for this is that the Ubuntu box's wireless adapter isn't supported by the default 10.04 install, so I need to connect Ubuntu to the net with a wired connection to update certain packages.)

Comment: Note: I had to disable my firewall

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your Mac:
System Preferences -> Sharing -> Internet Sharing

Share internet From Airport via Ethernet (the wording on that page of System Prefs is pretty close)

On Ubuntu:
Disable then re-enable the network and let it use DHCP to automatically get an IP and settings.

Unless you've customised your Mac's settings and firewall this should just work.

Answer (score 0):

`System Preferences -> Sharing -> Internet Sharing`

I don't think it will work with a single ethernet interface. I have never tried, but it looks like its allowing me to select Ethernet for both, client interface and shared interface on my MacBook Pro, but i can't test at the moment.